# Import namespace in .js file

Tags: javascript, .net

I am working on an MVC application and all the JavaScript for the pages is in their own JavaScript files, so there are no Script tags on the pages. Now, there is a Messages class that contains Errors, Information and Confirmation classes with Static strings. The error messages and information messages are being returned from the server, which is fine. But the confirmation messages (eg. Do you wish to Save (OK/Cancel), which is the confirm function in JavaScript) are hard coded in each JavaScript file. I now want the JavaScript to use the confirmation messages from the Messages.Confirmation class.

Currently, to solve this I do something like this in my page,

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Business.Common" %> 

.....

<script type="text/javascript">
    confirmSaveQuestion= '<%= Messages.Confirmations.CONFIRM_SAVE  %>';
</script>
```

and my .js file looks like this

```
var confirmSaveQuestion;

function ConfirmSave() {
    var result = window.confirm(confirmSaveQuestion);
    if (result)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and this works fine.

Is it possible to import the namespace Business.Common into the .js file, so that I don't have to set the value for confirmSaveQuestion in my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can't import namespace to my .js file, I went with a different solution. I removed the script tags from my page and instead added the following line of code. I guess it probably ends up doing a similar sort of thing, but it looks a bit cleaner.

```
<% Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().OnDocumentReady("confirmSaveQuestion = '" + Messages.Confirmations.CONFIRM_SAVE + "'"); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your .js files are static, so there is no way for them to interact with server code.  I'd recommend one of two things:

1) Use an ASHX handler to dynamically build javascript files - this will return your javascript dynamically, so that you can inject it with server stuff.  Instead of referencing a .js file in your markup, you would reference your .ashx file.

2) Put the `<%= %>` tags into your master page - still shows up on the page, but at least you only have to deal with them once.

Comment: Thanks for that. But, is it possible to give my js file a namespace that would be the same namespace as the one I wanted to import or somehow use jquery for this? This is just a shot in the dark and I apologise if it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Javascript (including jQuery) is client-only. It is only executed in the user's browser, so it has no idea about .NET namespaces, or any of your .NET code. So whatever you return to the browser (either static or dynamically-built) is completely stand-alone, and must have any constant values in it already. If you use an ASHX handler to build a dynamic "file" with your messages in it, then this handler will have access to the server code, so it can return the completed script to the browser.

Comment: +1 for your help. I think I'll just go with the ScriptRegistrar to solve this problem but I'll keep your solution in mind for future reference. Thanks again